Why Are My Hexbin Layers Not Visible in React-Leaflet?
I'm working on a React project using react-leaflet to display a hexbin layer on a map. Despite setting up the hexbin layer as per documentation and ensuring everything seems correct, the hexagons are not appearing on the map. Popups and other markers work fine, but the hexbin polygons are invisible.
Here’s a simplified version of my code to demonstrate the problem:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, useMap } from 'react-leaflet'
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
import L from 'leaflet'
import { hexbin as d3Hexbin } from 'd3-hexbin'
import { scaleLinear } from 'd3-scale'
import { max, mean } from 'd3-array'
import guestMarketingService from 'services/guest.marketing.service'
import { GMRestaurant } from 'assets/images'

type Coordinates = {
  lat: number
  lng: number
}

type CustomerLocation = Coordinates & {
  postalCode: string
  amount: number
}

async function getCoordinates(postalCode: string): Promise<Coordinates | null> {
  try {
    const data = await guestMarketingService.getAnalyticsHeatMapDetails({ postalCode })
    return data?.data?.data || null
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching coordinates:', error)
    return null
  }
}

const isValidLatLng = (lat: number, lng: number) => {
  return (
    typeof lat === 'number' &&
    typeof lng === 'number' &&
    !Number.isNaN(lat) &&
    !Number.isNaN(lng)
  )
}

const HexbinLayer = ({
  points,
  radius,
  colorRange,
}: {
  points: [number, number, number][]
  radius: number
  colorRange: string[]
}) => {
  const map = useMap()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (map) {
      const hexbin = d3Hexbin<[number, number, number]>()
        .radius(radius)
        .x((d) => d[0])
        .y((d) => d[1])

      const hexPoints = points.map(([lng, lat, amount]) => [lng, lat, amount] as [number, number, number])
      const hexbinData = hexbin(hexPoints)

      const colorScale = scaleLinear<string>()
        .domain([0, max(points, (d) => d[2]) || 1])
        .range(colorRange)

      const hexLayer = L.layerGroup().addTo(map)

      hexbinData.forEach((hex) => {
        const latLngs = hex.map(([x, y]) => L.latLng(y, x))
        const amount = mean(hex, (d) => d[2]) || 0
        const color = colorScale(amount)

        const polygon = L.polygon(latLngs, {
          fillColor: color,
          fillOpacity: 0.8,
          color: 'black', // Border color
          weight: 2,
          opacity: 1 // Ensure visibility
        }).addTo(hexLayer)
      })

      hexLayer.addTo(map)

      return () => {
        hexLayer.remove()
      }
    }
    return null
  }, [map, points, radius, colorRange])

  return null
}

const HexbinMap = ({
  postalCodeData,
  storePostalCode,
}: {
  postalCodeData: { postalCode: string; amount: number }[]
  storePostalCode: string
}) => {
  const [storeLocation, setStoreLocation] = useState<Coordinates | null>(null)
  const [customerLocations, setCustomerLocations] = useState<CustomerLocation[]>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const storeCoords = await getCoordinates(storePostalCode)
      setStoreLocation(storeCoords)
      const customerCoordsPromises = postalCodeData?.map(async ({ postalCode, amount }) => {
        if (postalCode != null) {
          const coords = await getCoordinates(postalCode)
          if (coords) {
            return { ...coords, postalCode, amount }
          }
        }
        return null
      })

      if (customerCoordsPromises !== undefined) {
        const customerCoords = await Promise.all(customerCoordsPromises)
        setCustomerLocations(customerCoords.filter(Boolean) as CustomerLocation[])
      }
    }

    fetchData()
  }, [postalCodeData, storePostalCode])

  const hexbinData = customerLocations.map((location) => [
    location.lng,
    location.lat,
    location.amount,
  ]) as [number, number, number][]

  return (
    <MapContainer style={{ height: '500px', width: '100%' }}>
      <TileLayer url="https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png" />
      {storeLocation && isValidLatLng(storeLocation.lat, storeLocation.lng) && (
        <HexbinLayer
          points={hexbinData}
          radius={100}
          colorRange={[
            'rgba(207, 249, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(85, 208, 255, 0.5)',
            'rgba(0, 128, 191, 0.8)',
          ]}
        />
      )}
    </MapContainer>
  )
}

export default HexbinMap


Issue:
Despite following the steps to render a hexbin layer, the hexagons are
not visible on the map. The popups and other markers work as expected.
I've tried setting different fill colors, adding borders, and
adjusting opacity, but nothing seems to make the hexagons appear.

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Verified that hexbinData contains valid data.
Added console logs to check coordinates and colors.
Ensured the hexagon layer is added after the map is initialized and other layers.
Tried various CSS and z-index adjustments.

Question:
What could be causing the hexbin layers to be invisible on the map, and how can I resolve this issue?
